# Why can't I suspend Ubuntu 14.04 (running from USB3) anymore?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb-flash-drive, suspend

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on an USB3.0 stick (Sandisk Extreme 64gb, both /root and /home are on it) as my portable development environment, mostly on an Asus N56VZ laptop.

Recently, Ubuntu fails to wake when suspended (it has worked before!). I get the standard unlocking screen, where I enter my password, after which it would tell me I entered the wrong password, which is definitely not the case. After this, everything basically freezes up.

To see what was going on I pressed Ctrl-Alt-F1, which showed me [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42894972/img/IMG_20140828_000237.jpg) (the log isn't saved anywhere, so I had to take a picture). It says something about an aborting a journal followed by loads of IO errors.

Apparently, it fails to mount /home (sdc5), or at least something like that, an thus everything fails and I have to hold the power button to shutdown the PC.

So the question is: *can I fix this and how*? If more info is found useful, I will gladly provide it.